# How to let the user select the layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to create a report where the user could choose not only what fields he wants, also the layout of this fields. All the data comes from a CSV and have lots of columns. I want to let the user choose what columns he wants to appear on the report header and body. For example if he choose 12 fields to be on the header and 3 columns on the body:

```
___________________________________________________________
  Field1: Field1Data           Field7: Field7Data    
  Field2: Field2Data           Field8: Field8Data
  Field3: Field3Data           Field9: Field9Data
  Field4: Field4Data           Field10: Field10Data            HEADER
  Field5: Field5Data           Field11: Field11Data
  Field6: Field6Data           Field12: Field12Data
  ___________________________________________________________
  ___________________________________________________________
  | Column1 |   Column2  |   Column3  |
  |  Data   |    Data    |    Data    |
  |  Data   |    Data    |    Data    |
  |  Data   |    Data    |    Data    |                       BODY
  |  Data   |    Data    |    Data    |
  |  Data   |    Data    |    Data    |
  ___________________________________________________________
```

Right now, I  let the user choose with data he wants on the report, using a select option with all the headers, push the index of the column he wants to an array, then create an object with the table and the header data, like this:

```
var arrayHeaderData = [0,1,2,3,..]

var headerDataObject = {
  table1: { Name: John, Location: 'Unknown', Age: 24},
  table2: { Name: John, Location: 'Unknown', Age: 24},
  table3: { Name: John, Location: 'Unknown', Age: 24}
}
```

I have multiple reports, that's why I store each data of a table in an object.

With this, I can append the data to each table, but the user cant choose which data he wants to appear first, for example, lets say he chose 12 fields and wants the field 3 to be on the right and the field 9 on the left

```
___________________________________________________________
  Field1: Field1Data           Field7: Field7Data    
  Field2: Field2Data           Field8: Field8Data
  Field9: Field9Data           Field3: Field3Data  <--He chose to swap this two
  Field4: Field4Data           Field10: Field10Data            HEADER
  Field5: Field5Data           Field11: Field11Data
  Field6: Field6Data           Field12: Field12Data
  ___________________________________________________________
```

I can't use something like UI-Sortable because there are more than one reports, so it wouldn't be practical to let the user change one field at the time for each report.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Can you not just use ui-sortable to let the user rearrange the fields, then use that new ordering to render the reports?

Comment: How would I do that, here is how I append the data to the header:                https://jsfiddle.net/p2tdc2bt/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `addClass` always work

sass:

```
.la1, .la2
    background: skyblue
    display: inline-block
    padding: 0.5em
    cursor: pointer

.content
    width: 70%
    background: #CCC
    color: #FFF
    height: 80%
    margin: 0 auto
    text-align: center
    font-size: 2em

    &.layer1
        text-align: left
        color: red
    &.layer2
        text-align: right
        background: #FAE98F
```

js:

```
$(function(){

    $(".la1").click(function(){
        $(".content").attr("class","content");
        $(".content").addClass("layer1");
    });


    $(".la2").click(function(){
        $(".content").attr("class","content");
        $(".content").addClass("layer2");
    });



});
```

http://jsbin.com/doxago/19/edit?output